# Differential Equation System With The Euler Method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I´m trying to learn to use the Euler method to solve a system of ODE's. I understand pretty clearly how to apply it when I have a single equation. But I stumbled uppon the following system which claims can be solved using Euler method:
\begin{cases} 
x' +y' = 4t\\
-x' +y' +y = 6t^2 +10
\end{cases}
Can anyone explain me how can I use the Euler method on this kind of systems?

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe try $u=x+y, v=-x+y$ and express $x,y$ in terms of $u,v$.

Comment: Or add and subtract both equations to find the explicit form of the system.

Comment: Is the explicit form of the system getting 2 equations of the form $x'=f(t,y) $and $y'=f(t,y)$ ?

Comment: @PabloEstrada: Essentially yes, but different $f$s for $x,y$.

Comment: Ok thank you very much :)

Comment: the solution is giving by $$\left\{ x \left( t \right) =-4\,{t}^{2}-2\,{{\rm e}^{-t/2}}{\it \_C1}
+20\,t+{\it \_C2},y \left( t \right) =6\,{t}^{2}-20\,t+2\,{{\rm e}^{-t
/2}}{\it \_C1}+50 \right\} 
$$